# Dataframe extracted from email, ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe extracted from email (email saved to local disk, ".msg"), that I am not able to read its content.

The dataframe extracted from email, when wrote to an Excel file, it looks like the screenshot.

It as extra lines on the front rows (#1, #2, #3) with grids. I've only worked with dataframe that normally has 1 top row (not sure if it's called Header).

What's wanted is to read the correspondent cells. For example, to get the First Name in the dataframe, I've tried:

```
first_name = df.loc[df['Field'] == 'First Name', 'Value'].iloc[0]
print (visitor_name)
```

It gives error:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

How can I do with this type of dataframe? (Here is the saved Excel file, https://filetransfer.io/data-package/6nOhcLTc#link)

[image]

Comment: Upload the file to Google, it seems to me it will be easier if it is available.

Comment: @inquirer, thank you for the comment. Sorry that it's a company internal email that I am not able to post the file.

Comment: What is the file type?

Comment: it's email format, ".msg".

Comment: thank you for your care! I can upload the saved Excel file, https://filetransfer.io/data-package/6nOhcLTc#link.

Comment: I replied, try your and my version of the first name query works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the following:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(df[df['Field'] == 'First Name']['Value'])
```

Output

```
6    David
```

If an error occurs, use the [link](https://techoverflow.net/2021/08/01/how-to-fix-pandas-pd-read_excel-error-xlrderror-excel-xlsx-file-not-supported/)

pip3 install openpyxl

Comment: thanks again for your patience and help! the raw file has duplicate rows that I only some time to work it out. :)

Comment: Now it's probably better to delete your file.